# Auto-seeding replica labels

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Is it possible to assign a unique seeded label to every instance/replica of a pod created by ReplicationController.
So if RC is set up to launch 4 replicas of a pod ABC - the replicas would have a label ABC-1,ABC-2 etc.
Help is appreciated

Comment: Use a StatefulSet.

Comment: ... and use an init container to extract the index from the pod name to set the label.

Comment: Once you have a StatefulSet, because the pod name is predictable, it could eliminate the need for separate labelling. Would be useful to know how the labels are being used.

Comment: If we have a replication factor of 4 - we would need the replica instances of that pod to be identifiable/labelled after launch as podABC-1,podABC-2,podABC-3 etc....so that they can have specific messages targeted to each

Comment: The pod name is the hostname, and when using a StatefulSet they would be named in that way with increasing number at end already, so not sure I see why that wouldn't be enough as that provides the way of looking them up. I guess it all really depends on what system you are trying to make this work with as to what is easier.

Comment: I believe we can achieve this in stateful sets without needing explicit PV.Given that,would there be too much overhead of using stateful sets vs replicationcontroller,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Graham, in your case it is a good idea to use StatefulSet:

> StatefulSets use an ordinal index for the identity and ordering of
>   their Pods. By default, StatefulSet Pods are deployed in sequential
>   order and are terminated in reverse ordinal order. For example, a
>   StatefulSet named web has its Pods named web-0, web-1, and web-2. When
>   the web Pod specification is changed, its Pods are gracefully stopped
>   and recreated in an ordered way; in this example, web-2 is terminated
>   first, then web-1, and so on.